# allowUnsafeRenegotiation without using System.setProperty("allowUnsafeRenegotiation","true")

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to use allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true directly in  my code without setting it in the properties is there a way to do it , can it be done through SSLContext class ??

Comment: Not sure what you mean? `System.setProperty( "sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true" );` that is the code? You can literally put that in code.

Comment: I want to set once when the code is built and not set it every time the code is used